# blockui requires jquery v1.2.3 or later you are using v.1.11.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Acually im using a higher version.

The error what is called is (Alert)

```
blockui requires jquery v1.2.3 or later you are using v.1.11.1
```

im not using wordpress or any other kind of programms/applications like this...

so solutions for wordpress won't help. i have a private project using jquery and jquery ui...

anyone knows the issue and how to fix this issue ?

Comment: i am using the version 2.37 and i found the check alert... guess i just have to fix the regexp condition :)

Comment: yes... it is a regex problem in the plugin

Comment: I had the same issue recently when i upgraded to new jQuery version and the answers here make sense, but one problem i am facing is i keep getting this alert and the blockUI does not work on all the pages unless the browser cache is deleted. Once i deleted my cache everything worked fine. However, this is not an obvious step for application users.  Any suggestions for how to avoid this?

Comment: @VishwaKumar could you please define what versions you are using ? jquery and jqueryUI

Comment: @Dwza I am using jQuery-1.12.4 and jQuery-ui-1.11.4. Also I Updated jquery.blockUi.js with latest code from http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#download

Comment: @VishwaKumar see my comment on Zsolti's post :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found the issue!

Here is a Fix for all who have the same problem

jquery.blockUI.js

```
// Old if condition
//if (/1\.(0|1|2)\.(0|1|2)/.test($.fn.jquery) || /^1.1/.test($.fn.jquery)) {

//new if condition
if ((/1\.(2\.([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])|[3-9]\.[0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)/.test($.fn.jquery)) === false ) {
```

total condition looks like

```
if ((/1\.(2\.([3-9]|[1-9][0-9])|[3-9]\.[0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]*)/.test($.fn.jquery)) === false ) {
    alert('blockUI requires jQuery v1.2.3 or later!  You are using v' + $.fn.jquery);
    return;
}
```

this will check the version from **1.2.3** up to **1.99~.99~**.

guess there will be a couple of years to reach this :D

Comment: i think the last part in my regex `\.[0-9]*` isn't even needed

Comment: I cant find the Old if condition on my jQuery file :S 
Are you sure it's there? `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` 
it's really hard to find stuff when the code is all mushed up :S

Comment: @ElectricWizard its not in the jquery-x.xx.x.js its in the jquery.blockUI.js

Comment: I changed it to console.log instead of an alert. So it's not totally gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to download and use the latest version of BlockUI:

[here](http://malsup.github.io/jquery.blockUI.js)

or

[here](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#download)

Comment: This would be the same if I would try to download latest version of jquery... sometime you don't want this because you may have a project that's build with a specific version. If you update than you will run into so many problems that its better to simply solve the used version.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid and delete this version check-up.

Remove this part from the blockui.js file:

```
 if (/1\.(0|1|2)\.(0|1|2)/.test($.fn.jquery) || /^1.1/.test($.fn.jquery)) {
alert('blockUI requires jQuery v1.2.3 or later!  You are using v', [$.fn.jquery]);
return;
```

}

Comment: Deleting a warning message may not be the best idea. What if there comes a jquery 3, your source breaks down and you don't know why. Not a solution for me. Warning messages have sence.

Comment: @Dwza What are you talking about??? This is just a if condition witch trigger a regex against the version number of the jQuery plugin. Removing it will never affect anything or breaks your application. I did and everything is fine since I updated my jQuery CDN as well.

Comment: Of course not the condition breaks down the source but may some part in the blockUI. And when this happens you propably never Finde out why. Just like I sayed...  If you like to decomment error messages... Go ahead. I mean you propably don't use all ui elements so may you don't use the one where the return result is needed. So this may is a solution for you :) anyways, it's never recommended to decomment any checks. Surly they have a reason.

Comment: By the way, it's not a simply if condition since it has a return in it.

Comment: @Dwza it only return false to stop the script in case there's a problem with the version. Conclusion it still a valuable solution to remove the check-up of the jQuery and yes it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: You sayed it by your self, it return false to stop the script in case there is a problem. So may in my jquery can be some more things that don't work and deleting the "on error stop" part will may cause a other error but it's hard to identify the reason because you deleted the check. Anyways...  This is to much discussion for me. You can make it like this but that's not a good solution.

Comment: @Dwza You seems to not understand what we are talking about since the beginning of this thread. Did you opened the file blockui.js? Did you look at the first line of the code, where the version is checked? I'm surely not. The script is independant from this if condition witch check the regex version and jQuery have absolutely nothing to do with this. Get it or not.

Comment: I cant find it on my UI file. 
Can you help me find it?
im using  jQuery UI - v1.11.4 - 2015-03-11

Comment: @ElectricWizard Did you tried to do a grep -r '/1\.(0|1|2)\.(0|1|2' on your JS files? It's just a if condition in the blockUI.js plugin.